# Vba to Vlookup with variable SheetName

Tags: excel, vba, variables, vlookup, variant

The following code portion should perform Vlookup with variable sheetname. However, the vlookup returns only 0's not the desired value from the lookup range, considering that the lookup range has the same structure across these multiple sheets with variable name, so any advise.

```
Dim SheetName As Variant: SheetName = DestinationWs.Name

Dim OldRemainingHoursLastRowFirst As Variant
OldRemainingHoursLastRowFirst = DestinationWs.Range("W3").End(xlDown).Row

DestinationWs.Range("L4").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],""'" & StringVal & "'!R4C12:R" & OldRemainingHoursLastRowFirst & "C14"",2,0),0)"
```

After performing the following code, this is the snapshot from the formula bar

[image]

Comment: Not a big R1C1 user, so can you express that formula in A1 notation?  I'm having problems seeing why you need INDIRECT here...

Comment: Indirect issue was solved after updating command to DestinationWs.Range("L4").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],INDIRECT(""'" & StringVal & "'!R[4]C[12]:R[" & OldRemainingHoursLastRowFirst & "]C[14]"",0),2,0),0)".  But the vlookup results always 0's. I'm using indirect to vlookup value through a variable sheet name based on input value

Comment: But you don't need the `INDIRECT()` here?  You're substituting the sheet name directly into the formula, so the `indirect` isn't needed.  Does each month sheet have a lookup table in the same range?

Comment: So you can say that I can directly insert variable sheet Name into the vlookup function without indirect fn! .. regarding the second point yes all other months sheets have the same lookup table in the same range but with different data. So what is your advise.

Comment: Enter the formula manually and get it working, then edit your post and add the working formula so we can see exactly what it should look like.

Comment: Post is updated and edited now, after take your advice into consideration.

Comment: Your formula is mixing R1C1 and A1 notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many quotes?

```vb
Dim SheetName As Variant
SheetName= DestinationWs.Name

DestinationWs.Range("L4").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],INDIRECT('" & _
             SheetName & "'!R[" & OldRemainingLastRowFirst & "]C[12]:R[" & _
             OldRemainingLastRowFirst & "]C[12]), 2, 0)"
```

After post updates:

```vb
    Dim srIndex, sMonth, destinationWs As Worksheet, lRow As Long
    Dim wsMonth As Worksheet, wsPrevMonth As Worksheet
    Dim selMonth, prevMonth, lRow As Longo
    
    '...
    
    selMonth = MonthResultRg.Cells(Application.match(CLng(InputValue), IndexRange, 0))
    prevMonth = MonthResultRg.Cells(Application.match(CLng(InputValue) - 1, IndexRange, 0))
    
    'reference selected and previous months' sheets
    Set wsMonth = FindSheet(ThisWorkbook, selMonth)
    Set wsPrevMonth = FindSheet(ThisWorkbook, prevMonth)
    lRow = wsPrevMonth.Range("W3").End(xlDown).Row
    
    wsMonth.Range("L4").Formula = _
      "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J4,'" & wsPrevMonth.Name & "'!L4:N" & lRow & ",2,0),0)"
```

`FindSheet` Function:

```vb
'return the first sheet in `wb` whose name contains `txt`
Function FindSheet(wb As Workbook, txt) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, txt, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set FindSheet = ws
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ws
End Function
```

Comment: Run-Time error '1004': Application-denfined or object-defined error

Comment: `Debug.Print` the formula and paste it into the cell.  Excel will tell you if there’s a problem

Comment: First of All, thanks so much for your help, It finally worked 
Please accept my poor knowledge. and once again thank you so much.

Comment: No problem - good to hear you got it working.